# Python sqlite3 Value Error

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite

I have been getting this error and have stuck a few hours trying to understand what I am doing wrong.  I have use this template for successfully importing into sqlite3 many many times in the past.

```
def TestImport():
   con = sqlite3.connect("test.db")
   con.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TestTable(ColA,ColB)")
   data=[('x','y')]
   stmt = "INSERT INTO TestTable VALUES(?,?)"
   con.execute(data,stmt)
   con.commit()
   con.close()
```

However this time I am getting this error:

```
ValueError: operation parameter must be str or unicode
```

here

```
con.execute(data,stmt)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
con.execute(stmt, data[0])
```